# Titanium - Android is not showing transparent colours for my views

Tags: android, titanium

I have the following index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="container" title="My App">
        <View backgroundImage="/myBackground.jpg">
            <Label backgroundColor='rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' text="Hello world!"></Label>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

As the documentation says, that should provide me with a Hello World text with a semi-transparent black background. In iOS works fine but it shows a totally transparent background on Android.

I tried putting it in a separate tss file but still the same issue. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason android compilations in Titanium don't work well with rgba() syntax for colors. Try the Hex version instead:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="container" title="My App">
        <View backgroundImage="/myBackground.jpg">
            <Label backgroundColor='#50000000' text="Hello world!"></Label>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```